# In the letter to Cramer, what is the implication or significance of being a North Dakotan or being Prairie tough?

Tags: united-states

Recently [a letter](https://www.wahpetondailynews.com/classifieds/other/ads/letter-to-cramer/pdfdisplayad_30637ad1-1360-5b3c-a01a-18ff134c1e61.html) was published in the Wahpeton Daily News (of Wahpeton, North Dakota) addressing Representative John Cramer. Here is a snippet:

> ...
>   That is prairie tough.
>   We are all survivors of domestic violence, sexual assault, or rape.
>   We are all North Dakotans.
>   We are all prairie tough.

It is available [here](https://blogs.mprnews.org/newscut/2018/10/heitkamp-metoo-open-letter-used-womens-names-without-permission/) too, but based on comments, some users in some areas may not have access to any of this material.

In this letter, what is the implication or significance of the victims being a North Dakotan or being Prairie tough ?

Comment: I have removed the possible answer as it normally does not belong with the question. SE allows to answer your own question, but make sure you include the proper references to support it.

Comment: also, when trying to access your link I receive `451: Unavailable due to legal reasons` (I am accessing from a country within EU). Please, include the relevant details in the post as citations.

Comment: @Alexei , thanks for the inputs ; I have included a snippet, and also another web-link.

Comment: @Machavity et al , I have reworded it to ask a specific question .

Comment: FYI there is a [Meta](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3674/how-can-i-improve-this-question-about-us-politics) post about this question.

Comment: @Alexei Wow, this question forces people to use proxies/VPNs. (People might not comply, of course)

Comment: "...of the victims..." Which victims? And what means "being Prairie"? I hardly understand what is meant by the question and I think it may not be very interesting to many others. If I would know more about why this is an interesting topic..

Comment: @Trilarion , I would not force you to read something you are not interested in , but the full letter may let you know about the victims. Even the small snippet I cited "We are all survivors of domestic violence" talks about the victims or survivors. No topic is interesting to all, otherwise every question here would have N upvotes and M downvotes such that M+N = total membership of PSE. You ask about meaning of "being Prairie" ; that is partially what I am asking.

Comment: @Prem I'm not really against some background reading, but I prefer the essential information of a question to be contained within the question text here. If you would already summarize the relevant content of the letter and give some more context I would not need to do that myself which would save me time. For example who is "we" in the snippet? Who sent the letter? Just a guess "being prairie" could mean something like "being tough guys or girls"??

Comment: Maybe this question would get more and better answers on https://english.stackexchange.com/ because a significant part of it seems to be about interpreting the English language.

Comment: @Trilarion , thanks for the support. The question has been edited couple of times and twice I had inserted some more context or guess about my answer. Now, the case is that one female candidate sent a letter to another male candidate, claiming to support and represent women of North Dakota and further claiming that the abuse victims were "Prairie strong". (CONT)

Comment: @Trilarion , (CONT) My contention was that the culprits were also men of North Dakota and hence were also "Prairie strong" so there is no sense to highlight that Point ; I gave an example of Spartans saying "We are Spartans !" when fighting Corinthians, to imply that "Spartans do not retreat; Spartans are tough !" ; My other contention was that, In Politics, such letters need not make sense, It needs to only be emotional and garner votes, for the female candidate in this case. I would imagine votes reading this and saying, "Yes, she is right, we are tough, I support here, I will vote for her".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a notion of "Praire Tough". It seems to have originally referred to the prairie soil, with a network of grass roots that broke conventional ploughs, and was then used to describe the tough and hardworking farmers who worked the prairies. This is an image that has been previously used in American literature:

> ... he was brought out here as a young bride... she seemed as if she was made for the prairie tough... nothing fazed her... designed for solitude and wide open spaces. (Home is where the Heart is, Linda Byler)

Traditionally it may have been associated with a certain kind of machismo: The ideal of praire tough would be a white, male farmer who, with gun and plough, subdues the land.

Now, logically there is nothing wrong with the statements:

> North Dakotan women victims of abuse are North Dakotan  (Tautology)
>   North Dakotan women victims of abuse are "Praire tough" (the claim)

It does not follow logically that "All North Dakotans are Praire tough".

Rhetorically this links a notion that makes North Dakotans proud to a particular subgroup, and implicitly suggests that abusers are not as "praire tough" and so are only North Dakotans in name, and not in attitude. It explicitly includes the Native Americans victims, to make the point that men that abuse Native American women should face justice within the tribal system.

This is rhetoric.  The significance is that women may have been seen as being victims, and so weak and not tough. The letter writer is making the opposite claim, and using rhetorical techniques to do this.

Comment: +1, James, thanks for the answer. (1) "a notion that makes North Dakotans proud": In an initial version of the Post, I used "a badge of honour" for this notion. (2) Even the culprits are North Dakotans and Prairie tough, that is where I am stuck. (3) If folks from neighbouring state or country were the culprits, this claim would make sense. (4) Words "women" and "girls" are mentioned elsewhere in the letter, but not in "We are all North Dakotans. We are all prairie tough." , implicitly including men, I guess, trying to garner votes from women as well as men. (5) Here the keyword is "rhetoric".

Comment: @Prem Culprits are silently excluded from "us", even though they may be equally from North Dakota. "We" are forming a bond of solidarity, and abusers are not welcome in that.

Comment: @Grault , I agree that "we" excludes the culprits, but the bond of solidarity is equally applicable to the culprits. Eg, the culprits can say "Yes, we attack women, because we are all prairie tough" [[ Even a businessman had talked about grabbing women by the private parts, and who knows how many votes that bond of solidarity brought in, to make him a President !! ]]

Comment: @Prem Yes, rhetorical tools are amoral and can be applied to any purpose. I'm not sure we're on-topic anymore, though.

Comment: @Grault , James is right that it is rhetoric, and your Point about "we" excluding the culprits is valid. Voters are swayed by Pride, rhetoric, badges of honour & bonds of solidarity, Politicians use anything and everything !!